# setTimeout within for loop, getting final value (waiting for for loop to finish)

Tags: javascript, loops

I have a for loop with a `setTimeout` function:

```
for (var i=0; i < variable; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        screenArray.push(takeScreen());
        sphere.rotateOnAxis(rotationVector, angle);
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
    }, 1);
}
```

The purpose there is to capture the `canvas` as a screenshot, rotate an object on the canvas, and repeat. Without the `setTimeout` function (even with a delay of 1), the canvas doesn't re-render fast enough before the canvas is capture and the screenshot looks weird.

The issue is that I would like do something with the array, `screenArray`, once everything is finished. But I can't seem to get anything to work. I'm just using `console.log(screenArray)` for testing for now, but the above simply logs `[]` to the console before it does the loop. Which I understand why (to a degree).

So I've been playing with callbacks, but every callback method I've tried either results in an error, `[]` multiple times, or `screenArray` being logged every interation of the loop (so it's not empty but it logs *variable* number of times). The following code does the latter (will output the array 4 times):

```
for (var i=0; i < screens; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() { loopWork(callback)  }, 1)
}
var callback = function(value) {
    console.log(value);
}
function loopWork(callback) {
    screenArray.push(takeScreen());
    sphere.rotateOnAxis(rotationVector, angle);
    renderer.render(scene,camera);
    callback(screenArray);
}
```

I even tried combining that with combining the for loop with a separate callback function, but that just resulted in the same thing as the above (though I may have done that incorrectly).

What I want is for it to simply log `screenArray` when the for loop has completed (which also means waiting for the `setTimeout`), but I just can't get that working.

Comment: You're passing `1` as the duration of the `setTimeout`? That's 1 millisecond, and all the timers start nearly exactly at the same time.

Comment: Yup, just `1`. I tried longer times, even up to `10000`, but that never changed anything. I'm not sure why `1` works (for the purpose to delaying the screenshot), but it does and I'm not going to question it right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to print the array when all the tiemouts have finished. Try this out:

```
var j=0;
for (var i=0; i < variable; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        screenArray.push(takeScreen());
        sphere.rotateOnAxis(rotationVector, angle);
        renderer.render(scene,camera);
        j++;
        if (j == variable) console.log(screenArray);
    }, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
----------
var screenCapture = (function(){
    var screenArray = [];
    return{
        loopScreen : function(length){
            var count = 0;
            var _this = this;
            var intvl = setInterval(function () {
                if(count < length){
                    _this.captureScreen(count);
                    count++;
                }else{
                    clearInterval(intvl);
                    console.log(screenArray);
                }
            }, 1)

        },
        captureScreen : function(val){
                 screenArray.push(val)
        }


    }

})()
screenCapture.loopScreen(10);
```